# How to change the kinect sensor view in RViz

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using kinect sensor for object recognition. Followed the below steps to see kinect sensor view in RViz.

1. Connected the kinect sensor to my desktop.
2. Ran "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch"
3. Ran "rosrun rviz rviz" and Set the Fixed Frame (in Global Options, Displays window) to /camera_depth_optical_frame. Added a PointCloud2 display and set the topic to /camera/depth/points.
4. Ran "rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure" and then selected /camera/driver from the drop-down menu and enabled the depth_registration checkbox.

The camera view in RViz is not proper according to the plane. It is showing upwards. Please let me know, how to change the settings to make the view proper. The expected view should be [link text](http://wg-perception.github.io/ork_tutorials/_images/Screenshot_2014_11_07_13_24_46.png)

**Platfrom:** Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285790/how-to-change-the-kinect-sensor-view-in-rviz/) by [Nitin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34183/nitin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`depth_optical_frame` has `z+` pointing forward (ie: into the world). As Rviz global frame has `z+` upwards (ie: out of the `xy` plane), your pointcloud is projected "onto the ceiling". You'll have to publish a transform between your `Fixed Frame` and (most likely) the `camera_link` to change this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1